# Adding transition Animation to objects in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a simple animation at the moment which as the user slides from left to right a box (UIView) slides in. Is it possible to add a UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition so the animation gets completed depending on how far the user has moves his/her finger across the screen, or are they only available when switching between Views.